# how to read file and print in reverse order using stack C++

Tags: c++, stack, file-handling

I have to read text file each word at a time and then push that word to stack and then pop each word at a time to print in the display. I have tried the following code but after running the program, compiler just shows the blank screen with no error. 
NOTE: 
I am not allowed to implement the stack using a class or struct or with STL. The stack must be implemented using a fixed size array of words and an index integer for indicating the top of the stack

My text file is something like:

```
one two three four five
six seven and so on
```

output should be:

```
no os dna neves xis ...
```

main.cpp

```
using namespace std;

char word;
void push(char);
void pop();
void displaywords();

int count = 0;
const int arr_Size=50;
string stack[arr_Size];

int main()
{
    //string word;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("data.txt");
    if(!infile)
    {
        cerr << "An error occurred while opening the file.";
        exit(1);
    }

    do
    {
        cin >> word;
        if (infile.fail())
            break;
        cout << word;   
        push(word);     
    }while(infile.eof());
    infile.close();

    while(stack!=NULL) // trying to write code for stack is not null
    {
        displaywords();
        pop();
    }
    return 0;
}

void push(char word)
{
    count = count + 1;
    stack[count] = word;
}

void displaywords()
{
    cout << "PUSHED " << " " << stack[count] << "   ." << endl;
}

void pop()
{
    count = count - 1;
}
```

Comment: There is also [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).  No need to roll your own one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has quite a few problems. One obvious one is that the reading loop has `while(infile.eof())` as its condition. That's almost certainly not what you want. `while(!infile.eof())` is probably what you were thinking of, but that doesn't really work correctly/dependably either.

You're also opening `infile` but when you read, you try to read from `cin` instead of `infile`.

You also attempt to use `while(stack!=NULL)`, with the apparent intent of reading until the stack is empty--but `stack` is an array. It'll never compare as equal to NULL.

Since you're using C++, I'd use a standard container (e.g., `std::vector` or `std::deque`, with or without the `std::stack` adapter) instead. Something on this general order should be a bit closer:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
std::infile("some file.txt");
std::string word;

while (infile >> word)
    strings.push_back(word);

while (!strings.empty()) {
    std::cout << strings.back();
    strings.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to implement the stack using a class or struct or with STL. The stack must be implemented using a fixed size array of words and an index integer for indicating the top of the stack

Comment: @muzzi: Well, then go ahead and do that--though if it were me, I'd still create a `stack` class of my own, so the rest of the code would just deal with a stack at an abstract level (push, pop. top). Oh, and based on the edit to the question, you really want to read one character at a time, and put single characters on the stack, not whole words.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are trying to read from `cin`. Change the `cin` in the `do` block to `infile`.

Answer (score 1):

std::cin reads from stdin.  You're not going to get anything out of your streambuffer - it's waiting for user input.